# Trying to refresh page using Jquery post and ActionResult

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, http-post, redirecttoaction

I've been trying to make the "RedirecttoAction" statement work here but it doesn't budge. Here is the method:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UpdateTech(int tech, int id)
    {
        Callout callout = db.Callouts.Find(id);
        callout.TechnicianId = tech;
        callout.TechStatus = "ASSIGNED";
        db.Entry(callout).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("CalloutAdmin/Index/");
    }
```

And it is called by the following JQuery, which works perfectly:

```
$(function () {
        $(".techdropdown").change(function () {
            var recordToUpdate = $(this).attr("id");
            var selectedTech = $(".techdropdown option:selected").val();
            window.alert(selectedTech);
            $.post("/CalloutAdmin/UpdateTech?tech=" + selectedTech + "&id=" + recordToUpdate);
        });
    });
```

The only thing that does not happen is the page being refreshed, which was what the redirect should do. Can anyone advise?

**UPDATE**

What I am trying to do is update this Callout object, without redirecting to another view. I choose a technician from a dropdownlist and it automatically sets the callout's technician value to the one I chose from the dropdown.

Comment: Could you explain exactly what it is your trying to achieve, as i feel you may have become confused somewhere. You shouldn't need to use jQuery's AJAX loading if you want to redirect the page?
I will add an answer that I believe will work for what you what but if you could give more details in your question it would help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're returning the redirect to the AJAX request, and the AJAX request is loading the page in the background. If you want to have the entire page redirect you probably want to use the success callback in jQuery

```
$.post("/CalloutAdmin/UpdateTech?tech=" + selectedTech + "&id=" + recordToUpdate, function() { document.location = "CalloutAdmin/Index/"; } );
```

If you want to have the action control the location of the redirect, you probably want to use the return a `JsonResult` or `ContentResult` from your action with the URL outputted from there have jQuery's success callback redirect the user.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that UpdateTech and Index both belong to CallOutAdminController then change your UpdateTech Method to look like:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UpdateTech(int tech, int id)
{
    Callout callout = db.Callouts.Find(id);
    callout.TechnicianId = tech;
    callout.TechStatus = "ASSIGNED";
    db.Entry(callout).State = EntityState.Modified;
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index","CallOutAdmin");
}
```

Then make you jQuery function like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $(".techdropdown").change(function () {
        var recordToUpdate = $(this).attr("id");
        var selectedTech = $(".techdropdown option:selected").val();
        window.alert(selectedTech);
        window.location = "/CallOutAdmin/UpdateTech?tech=" + selectedTech + "&id=" + recordToUpdate
    });
});
```

Comment: window.location = "/CalloutAdmin/UpdateTech?tech=" + selectedTech + "&id=" + recordToUpdate did not work, it told me it can't find the method UpdateTech

Comment: Then UpdateTech doesn't exist in the controller for CallOutAdmin...
try updating "/CalloutAdmin/UpdateTech?tech=" to "/CallOutAdmin/UpdateTech?tech=" as depending on your settings it maybe case sensitive.